# Optimize MATLAB code (nested for loop to compute similarity matrix)

Tags: optimization, matlab

I am computing a similarity matrix based on Euclidean distance in MATLAB. My code is as follows:

```
for i=1:N % M,N is the size of the matrix x for whose elements I am computing similarity matrix
 for j=1:N
  D(i,j) = sqrt(sum(x(:,i)-x(:,j)).^2)); % D is the similarity matrix
 end
end
```

Can any help with optimizing this = reducing the for loops as my matrix `x` is of dimension `256x30000`.

Thanks a lot!

--Aditya

Comment: If you have Statistics toolbox the function pdist does exactly this in an optimised way. help pdist; help squareform

Comment: Its true that pdist is a Matlab function but its FAR from being optimized.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The function to do so in matlab is called pdist. Unfortunately it is painfully slow and doesnt take Matlabs vectorization abilities into account.

The following is code I wrote for a project. Let me know what kind of speed up you get.

```
   Qx=repmat(dot(x,x,2),1,size(x,1));
   D=sqrt(Qx+Qx'-2*x*x');
```

Note though that this will only work if your data points are in the rows and your dimensions the columns. So for example lets say I have 256 data points and 100000 dimensions then on my mac using x=rand(256,100000) and the above code produces a 256x256 matrix in about half a second.

Comment: +1, that's a sweet solution! Although mine is vectorized, just storing the indices and accessing them bogs it down at large N. Yours works great even when # of dimensions is 256 and # of points is 20000. It gave me a 2e4x2e4 matrix in about 10 seconds, whereas mine ran out of memory.

Comment: I initially had the same problem which is why I had to figure out the correct way to do it. That simple bit of code took ages to arrive at. But it saved days of computing time:)

Comment: you're right. Unless you really need it, that's not a solution you'd think of right away. Since my needs until now were for `1000x3` or similar sizes, my solution seemed blazing fast when compared to loops. Not once did I think of its performance for large N. Kudos to you :)

Answer (score 1):

There's probably a better way to do it, but the first thing I noticed was that you could cut the runtime in half by exploiting the symmetry `D(i,j)==D(i,j)`

You can also use the function `norm(x(:,i)-x(:,j),2)`

Comment: Norm is the right way to do it per entry. However its quite easy to vectorize it.

Answer (score 1):

I think this is what you're looking for.

```
D=zeros(N);    
jIndx=repmat(1:N,N,1);iIndx=jIndx'; %'# fix SO's syntax highlighting
D(:)=sqrt(sum((x(iIndx(:),:)-x(jIndx(:),:)).^2,2));
```

Here, I have assumed that the distance vector, `x` is initalized as an `NxM` array, where `M` is the number of dimensions of the system and `N` is the number of points. So if your ordering is different, you'll have to make changes accordingly.

Comment: Props to you for doing it without explicit looping, but this code doesn't scale to the size of the problem at hand, and at least on my machine with MATLAB 2009b, is still single-threaded. With M=256, memory usage passes 4GB when N grows a bit beyond 1000 (and that's *after* I switched to 32-bit data types). The question wants N=30000. At that size, the intermediate matrices like `x(iIndx(:),:)` will take up a total of about 2TB. Unless more recent versions of MATLAB are very good at lazy evaluation, this can't work.

Comment: ah good catch, I hadn't seen the size of the array! In fact, just the `D` matrix, no matter what method you use to arrive at it, is ~6GB!

Comment: You dont need to store the values. Each matrix entry is just |x|^2-2*x'*y+|y|^2. This can be evaluated quite fast using Matlab vectorization

Answer (score 0):

To start with, you are computing twice as much as you need to here, because D will be symmetric. You don't need to calculate the (i,j) entry and the (j,i) entry separately. Change your inner loop to `for j=1:i`, and add in the body of that loop `D(j,i)=D(i,j);`

After that, there's really not much redundancy left in what that code does, so your only room left for improvement is to parallelize it: if you have the Parallel Computing Toolbox, convert your outer loop to a `parfor` and before you run it, say `matlabpool(n)`, where `n` is the number of threads to use.